# Using linq with c#

Tags: c#, linq

I never used linq before but want to start using it in my code.

I have 2 string arrays.

```
 string[] allFruits = allFruitTextHiddenBox.Text.Value.Trim('|').Split('|');
 string[] healthyFruits = GetHealthyFruits().Trim('|').Split('|');

 // now I need to get rotten fruits which are ones  allfruit - healthyfruits

 // I need string[] rottenFruits please
```

Just not sure how to do it using linq.

Comment: Have you already tried anything? Have you done some basic learning of linq???

Comment: I advise reading ["Getting Started with LINQ in C#"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397933.aspx).

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth Thanks, going to now

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`Enumerable.Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which produces the set difference:

```
var rotten = allFruits.Except(healthyFruits);
```

If you need an array again use `ToArray`.

Answer (score 3):

The `Except` extension method is certainly the best way to do what you're asking for, but strictly speaking it is not LINQ. LINQ is "Language Integrated Query" and is the application of certainly extension methods in a way that they are integrated into the language.

So, for example, to code your request using LINQ you would do this:

```
var query =
    from fruit in allFruits
    where !healthyFruits.Contains(fruit)
    select fruit;

var results = query.ToArray();
```

Just being a bit nit-picky. :-)

Comment: + 1: `System.Linq` is required, to make `Except` work, so it kinda is. But you are right.

Comment: @MaxMommersteeg - Good one. It's nice to see I'm not the only one being picky. LOL

Comment: It's all LINQ, what you describe it's the distinction between Query Syntax and Method Syntax. Actually the query syntax is translated to method syntax, so i'd say it's the opposite of what you claim.

Answer (score 1):

try like this

```
var fruits = allFruits.Except(healthyFruits);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Now I need to get rotten fruits which are ones  allfruit - healthyfruits
>   I need string[] rottenFruits please

Create a new string array and fill it with allfruits, not included in healthyFruits and convert it to an array:

```
string[] rottenFruits = allFruits.Except(healthyFruits).ToArray();
```

Don't forget to add: `using System.Linq;` at the top of your class.